# iPhone: how to NSArray content to NSDictionary

Tags: iphone, nsarray

I want to add content of NSArray's to NSDictionary r NSMultDictionary.

I have NSDictionary(empty), and I have NSArray with content and I have to store NSArray content in NSDictionary.

How can I do this?

Comment: ok i will do that Jacob Relkin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add content of NSArray to NSDictionary by using following code.

```
NSMutableDictionary *dic = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
for(int i=0; i<[Array count]; i++){
[dic setObject:[Array objectAtIndex:i] forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i]];
}
```

The dic is the dictionary, you can use that.

Or else you can add whole array as one object in the dictionary as

```
NSMutableDictionary *dic = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[dic setObject:Array forKey:@"array"];
```

Comment: hi satya,i am working on twitter,i get information for server and stored in array(ie in deleage ) then i have to store in Dictionary and use it so that, can you tell me for this

Comment: I am wondering why you have to store the data into the dictionary, you can use that data from array also. And in case if you want that data in the dictionary you need some keys for each value. Or else you can store whole array as a single object in the dictionary.

Comment: you can store whole array as a single object in the dictionary.how to do this, satya, this real helps me

Comment: i am sorry satya i getting warning, from twitter server, i get information(ie userName, ScreenName, Location etc) into array(upto here is delegate) and now i have to store in Dictionary and in Dictionary is compare with string and that values i show on UILabel and if image means show on UIImageview like, Please Satya tell me

Comment: kishore, one thing you have to check. I think, you will get that information from the server will be in dictionary format not in array. can you check once again. Or else if you tel that service, I will check here.

Answer (score 0):

@Nandakishore suppose you have an array eg:-myArray

```
NSDictionary *A = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:myArray forKey:@"Key"];
```

Now this dictionary object(A) has all the content of the `myArray`......now do what u wanna do with your dictionary

I hope this may help you!

Comment: yes Sudhanshu can i use like this NSDictionary *A = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:myArray];

Comment: @NandKishore, dictionary is a kind of hashmap which having key value pair.So here key is require for setting an object.Without key how will you access the object.

Comment: @Ishu i agree with u.....@Nandkishore key is necessary in order to access the objects from dictionary.